# Google maps API: how to embed a URL link under a marker and open the page when clicked

Tags: mysql, google-maps, dom, google-maps-markers

I have created a google maps with markers. The markers are getting their information from a mysql database. I have id, name, adress, lat, lng, type and url. In the URL i have placed a link to the restaurant and want it to open when i click on the marker. However, when i click on the marker the page is changing but it is going to a blank page saying 'The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server.' If someone could help me to see where I have gone wrong it would be appreciated. This is my HTML code:

```
<script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.8980, -8.4737),
      zoom: 16
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl('locator.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var url = markerElem.getAttribute('url');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text)

          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label

          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {      
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            window.location.href = this.url;

          });
        });
      });
    }


  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.url` is undefined.  You never set it in your code.

Add it to the `MarkerOptions` object:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: point,
  label: icon.label,
  url: url
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {      
  infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  console.log("marker click, this.url="+this.url);
  if (!!this.url) {
    window.location.href = this.url;
  }
});
```